# How to disable button for some user?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a table in a database which has a column of UserName and UserRights. UserRights is either `admin` or `user`
Now, I want to disable some of buttons in another form if the UserName used to login in the `login form` is only a user. How will i do that? 
I have the codes below:

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = null;
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select* from TableAcct", connection);
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            uname.Add(reader["username"].ToString());
            password.Add(reader["userpassword"].ToString());
            rights.Add(reader["rights"].ToString());
        }
        connection.Close();

        int totalItems = uname.Count;
        int count = 0;
        string isValidated = "";
        while (count < totalItems)
        {
            if ((Username.Text == uname[count].ToString()) && (pword.Text == password[count].ToString()))
            {
                isValidated = "True";
                rights2 = rights[count].ToString();
                count = 100;
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (isValidated == "True")
        {
            Mainform mainform1 = new Mainform();
            login.ActiveForm.Hide();
            mainform1.linkLabel1.Text = Username.Text;
            mainform1.ShowDialog();
            Username.Clear();
            pword.Clear();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Log in. Please try again", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

Comment: check if UserRights is user set button1.Enabled = false;

Answer (score 1):

Save the login user name in session or any container.Get that username in different form and apply a condition if it's ok then use

```
buttonname.visible = true
else
buttonname.visible = false.
```

if you will use visible property then put your button in visible=false mode initially in html code.

Or you may use

```
buttonname.enable = true
else
buttonname.enable = false
```

i think it will help for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can either pass true or false to the main-form. Or you create a class for a user which contains the usermode (admin or user-enum) and the username and so on.

The constructor of your mainform accepts the user-object as parameter and in the constructor after the InitializeComponent() you can do something like:

```
public Mainform(User user)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   if(user.UserType == UserType.User)
   {
      // Make your buttons invisible
      buttonOnlyForAdmins.Visible = false;
   }
}
```

Instead of setting the buttons invisible you also can make the "admin-buttons" invisible per default and only set them visible if the user is admin.

User can be a class like:

```
public class User
{
   public string Username{get;set;}
   public UserType UserType{get;set}
}
```

Comment: UserRights is a column in a database and its values is either `admin` or `user`. and what is `User` in public Mainform(User user)